# Construction of a convex function nondifferentiable on a countable set

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, convexity

Let $H$ be a countable subset of $[0,1]$. Construct a convex function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is nondifferentiable on $H$ and differentiable in the rest.

Comment: Why do you think such a function might exist? Why do you need to know?

Comment: Hm, I'd rather not.

Comment: Based on the fact that the set of nondifferentiablity points for a convex function is countable, the reverse problem, which I stated, arises quite natural. I've got some ideas, but they seem to work only for some particular sets.

Comment: The second antiderivative of a finite discrete measure concentrated in $H$.

Answer (score 2):

If you think in terms of constructing the derivative of $f$ rather than $f$ itself, you're looking for an increasing function that has an arbitrary countable set $H$ of discontinuities.  There's a standard trick to do this: choose an injection $i:H\to\mathbb{N}$, and define $$g(x)=\sum_{h<x, h\in H} 2^{-i(h)}.$$
If you then define $f$ by integrating $g$, it will be convex and differentiable everywhere except on $H$.

Comment: Like shooting fish in a barrel. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Enumerate $H$ as $h_1, h_2, \ldots$, and take 
$f(x) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty 2^{-j} |x - h_j|$.